# grqreg with categorical variables

Tags: graph, error-handling, regression, stata, quantile

I am using the SSC command `-grqreg-` to graph the quantile regressions for my equation. I have been able to graph the single equation successfully; however, I am now trying to split the sample and estimate separately. The code and error are as follows:

[image]

I assume this error occurs because when the model is split, there are no observations for one of the content indicators. How should I troubleshoot this? The error occurs even when varlist excludes the indicator variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is clunky, but you just need to drop the omitted variables first:

```
sysuse auto, clear
fvunab rhs: weight length i.f* i.rep* 
xi: qreg price `rhs' if foreign == 1

/* remove any variables prefixed with o. and the constant */
matrix list e(b)
local rhs2: colnames e(b)
di "`coefs'"
local rhs2 =  ustrregexra("`rhs2'","o\._I[a-zA-Z_0-9]+ ","") 
local rhs2 =  ustrregexra("`rhs2'","_cons","") 

/* Fit the model again with non-omitted variable set */
qreg price `rhs2' if foreign == 1
grqreg, cons ci ols olsci
```

Note that it is considered polite to tell people when [cross-posting](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1432100-grqreg-with-caterogical-variables) on different fora.